# How to add Listener for PictureScrollField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am implementing a PictureScrollField in my application. I do not know how to set Listener for images in PictureScrollField. I tried with navigationClick,navigationMovement, fieldChange,trackwheelclick and touchevent. But nothing is working properly. navigationClick,navigationMovement, fieldChange are not working at all , trackwheel working one after that it will not work and touchevent works for the whole PictureScrollField not for the specific image. Somebody help me please.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you're trying to know when a new picture gets into view or when it is clicked / taped?

Comment: when a picture is clicked/taped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NavigationClick is the way to go. However, you will need to check if the field is in focus and then get the selected index. Try the following code:

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

        // psf is the PictureScrollField //

        if (psf.isFocus()) {

            switch (psf.getCurrentImageIndex()) {
            case 0:
                // Action when image at index 0 is clicked
                break;

            case 1:
                // Action when image at index 1 is clicked
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.navigationClick(status, time);
    }
```

Comment: post your code what you've done so far, I can't tell what's wrong until I see the code.

Comment: take a look here: [PictureScrollField Menu](http://betweenzeroandone.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/blackberry-creating-a-slick-picturescrollfield-menu/)